# Can Lua use the Pythagorean Thereom?

Tags: lua, geometry

I'm currently on a problem in Lua where in order to calculate the distance from a point I need the Pythagorean Thereom. Is it possible to do this equation in Lua? If not are their work arounds?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. Take this as a good opportunity to learn basic Lua. See *Programming in Lua* section 2.3 [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html) for numbers and section 18 [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/18.html) for using the standard Lua math library.

Comment: Okay Thanks! I knew about the numbers but just read and will use your document on math!